# Anyone know why this question isn't showing up on the main C SE page?

Tags: discussion

This question

[According to Trinitarians who believe Philippians 2:6 says Jesus is God, why did Paul add the word 'form' ('morphe')?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93844/according-to-trinitarians-who-believe-philippians-26-says-jesus-is-god-why-did)

doesn't seem to be showing up on the main C SE page. Anyone know why that might be?

Comment: It is showing up on my electronic devices.

Comment: @KenGraham Weird. Can you confirm that isn't the previously migrated and once-in-5-years closed by PT one?

Comment: All looks okay from where I am, but SE may be experiencing a bug at the moment. I am sure it will be resolved in time.

Comment: -4 will do that to a question, as some politician said somewhere, votes matter!

Comment: @PeterTurner Can you say more? At a certain number of dv's does a question disappear from the main page?

Comment: Yes, if it's under -3 net votes it's hidden from the main page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the algorithm, but in practice a question with a lot of downvotes will get bumped off the main page, you should still be able to see it if you go to [questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions)

But the "main page" contains the hot questions, what the system determines is least bad and I'm sorry if you're getting DV's for this line of questioning, it might be that users legitimately don't think these kinds of questions are worth asking.

I think I've asked as many questions on this site as anyone (except maybe the Spirit Realm Investigator of happy memory) and sometimes this just happens.

If there's a conspiracy to downvote your questions personally, I think the system does a good job of picking up on that and attempting to rectify it.  Though I don't get to see (or if I did see I couldn't tell) the outcome of those processes.

Comment: "But the "main page" is the hot questions" No, it's not. I have the 'Active' option selected (which I believe is the default).

Comment: [The "algorithm" is a score of -4 or less will not show on the front page. (or -8 on meta sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/674198).